# Query regarding subdomain redirection in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was looking for an approach using Zend Framework - similar to sites like bit.ly and tinyurl -  where I can take a request to a subdomain and store the subdomain in a variable.

For instance, a request to localhost/abcdef will return $s = abcdef. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in ZF, where a request to localhost/abcdef will return the init() of the abcdef controller.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regex route.

```
$routeitem = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('(.*)',
                    array(1 => '', 'controller' => 'redir', 'action' => 'view'),
                    array(1 => 'hash'),
                    '%s'
    );
```

You can then get your "hash" redirection from the _getParam method.

Comment: First of all, thanks ... you have been tremendously helpful!

The problem is that I seem to be encountering circular redirects. Is there anyway to have Zend_Controller_Router redirect to the default controller/action _unless_ controller doesn't exist? 

In other words, instead of **returning page not found** to a request to localhost/abcdef, store abcdef in a variable, while a request to localhost/controller will call init().