# Conditional subdomains

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom domain name mapping to user profile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515644/custom-domain-name-mapping-to-user-profile)

I am working on a new project and want to know if this is possible with codeigniter and how.
In this application visitors get to open an account, now when their account is opened, to access their dashboard, they should go to their username dot the domain name like so, `username.domain.com`, I saw this on a site and really liked it so i was wondering if i could do the same with codeigniter and how.

Comment: It's not specific to codeigniter - Using a wildcard DNS entry as described in the linked answer, you need a rewrite rule which matches the subdomain and passes it to PHP via `$_GET`.

Comment: [Here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976475/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subdomain-to-page) which explains how to match the subdomain and pass it into the rewritten URI

Answer (score 0):

`username.domain.com` is not based on **codeigniter** the part *username.* is called **subdomain** which is provided by the host. it has its own CGI scripts and can be considered as a folder with ability to host a code.

so if your hosting has an **API** that gives you a control over *subdomains* of your domain. then it's a matter of coding. So whether to use codeigniter or another framework it will not make a difference.

Hope that was helpful.